# Как сделать что бы MessageBox закрылся через 3 секунды

Tags: visual-c++

```
int DisplayResourceNAMessageBox;
{
    int msgboxID = MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR)L"Обнаружено запрещенное программное обеспечение!", (LPCWSTR)L"Ошибка", MB_ICONWARNING | MB_SYSTEMMODAL | MB_SETFOREGROUND);
    switch (msgboxID)
    {
        case IDOK:
            ExitProcess(pid);
            break;
    }
    return msgboxID;
}
```

Comment: Помнится была незадокументированная WinAPI функция `MessageBoxTimeout`. Но всё же, главный вопрос - зачем? Вы хотите уведомить пользователя? Зачем давать ему шанс пропустить ваше уведомление?

Answer (score 0):

MessageBoxTimeout API находится в библиотеке user32.dll.

Прототип:
int MessageBoxTimeout(int* hwnd, string text, string title, uint type, short wLanguageId, int milliseconds);

[Подробнее](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7914/MessageBoxTimeout-API?msg=894080)